# Using debug mode, when running a pytest test with FastAPI app, in VSCode

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, vscode-debugger

I'm  following the information in [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) official VSCode documentation
I get a discovery error, and the message is:

```
[n [Error]: ============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /path/to/dir/with/tests
configfile: ../../pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-3.6.2
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
________________________ ERROR collecting test_crud.py _________________________
test_crud.py:11: in <module>
    from app.main import app
../../app/main.py:10: in <module>
    import db.schemas
../../db/schemas.py:8: in <module>
    from db.db_orm import Base
../../db/db_orm.py:13: in <module>
    postgres_user = os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"]
/usr/lib/python3.10/os.py:679: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'POSTGRES_USER'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_crud.py - KeyError: 'POSTGRES_USER'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
===================== no tests collected, 1 error in 0.26s =====================
```

It detects the file, but then, it seems that I'm not loading some environmental variables...

However, when I run `uvicorn app.main:app --reload`, everything works fine, and I'm able to connect to the database, and serve requests...
If I run pytest from the terminal, I'm also able to run the tests.

Comment: How are you setting your environmental variables when running normally?